# Why there is need to add 'POST' method in both list_allowed_methods as well as detail_allowed_methods in Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, tastypie

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['post']
    resource_name = 'myapp/entry'
```

Why there is need to add "POST" in detail_allowed_methods, As I comment detail_allowed_methods "POST" work fine..!

Answer (score 1):

It works fine because on commenting out `detail_allowed_methods`, Tastypie falls back to it's default value, which is:

```
['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
```

So, commenting `detail_allowed_methods` won't do anything. If you want to disable all methods, set it's value to an empty list:

```
detail_allowed_methods = []
```

[See Tastypie docs](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=allowed_method#detail-allowed-methods).

Comment: True, According to docs default value of detail_allowed_methods will set to `['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']`, if detail_allowed_methods is commented. but why detail delete not works as it is allowed in  detail_allowed_methods

Answer (score 0):

Posting to list endpoint and posting to detail one has a different meaning. As from [Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#creating-a-new-resource-post):

> To create new resources/objects, you will POST to the list endpoint of a resource. Trying to POST to a detail endpoint has a different meaning in the REST mindset (meaning to add a resource as a child of a resource of the same type).

If you want to allow the same methods for both list and detail you can use `allowed_methods` which covers both. If you instead want to use different methods between the two, you need to specify allowed methods for each endpoint.

As @xyres said, specifying methods for one endpoint only, will results in the other one falling back on its default (all methods allowed).